# XGetImage from hidden screen

Tags: x11, xlib

I'm using Xlib for my application and would like get image from root window
I open separated Xserver in another tty (:1) then opened this diplay

> XGetDisplay(":1")

I'm working in :0 display
After I get default screen and root window and want to get image of this root window
Unfortunately I've got only black screen if my window is hidden
Can I someway force X11 to render window if it's hidden?

Answer (score 2):

When not visible on screen X11 windows don't have to keep their surface pixmaps. You can force this with [Composite extension](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/compositeproto/compositeproto.txt), [NameWindowPixmap request](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xcompositenamewindowpixmap)

Comment: If I run `XCompositeRedirectWindow()` and `XCompositeNameWindowPixmap()` I still get a `BadMatch` if the window is minimised. So, this only works if the window is obscured, i.e. open and behind an active window? Is there any way to get from a minimised window?

Comment: it should not matter if obscured or not, likely some mismatch in the parameters between the window and arguments to your XCompositeRedirectWindow / XCompositeNameWindowPixmap calls